# mysql php doing loop method

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i'm new to the php code here is the problem i want to slove

1. Let say we have event[ eid,pid,start_time,end_time,date ]=[kim,34,2:00:00,4:00:00,2013-12-25]

and if I want to print the 'range' of certain date.
for example I enter the dates such as

begin = 2012-12-23
end  = 2012-12-25

and I want to print all the events between those dates. 
should i put some for loop functionality to query? or

```
$result2 =mysql_query("
select eid,description
from event natural join eventdate
where pid = '$pid'
and edate = '$edate'
}
```

or here

```
if($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo"<table border=1>\n";
  echo"<tr><th>pid<th>edate<th>description<th> schedule I invited and accept</tr>\n";
  do{
    printf("<tr><td>%s<td>%s<td>%s<td></tr>\n",$myrow["pid"],$myrow["edate"],$myrow["description"]);
  }while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: You may want ignore tutorials that refer to mysql_query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all rows where `edate` falls into a specific range of dates and assuming that `edate` is of type `date` you can do

```sql
SELECT e.eid, e.description
  FROM event e JOIN eventdate d
    ON e.eid = d.eid
 WHERE pid = '$pid'
   AND edate BETWEEN '$range_start_date' AND '$range_end_date'
```

**On a side note:** Consider to learn and use prepared statements with either `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of interpolating query strings.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08d14/1)** demo

---

Your php code might look something like

```php
$pid = 34;
$edate = '"2013-12-23"-"2013-12-25"';
list($range_start_date, $range_end_date) = explode('"-"', trim($edate, '"'));

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'userpwd', 'test');
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $db->connect_error); //TODO: better error handling
}

$sql = "SELECT e.eid, e.description
  FROM event e JOIN eventdate d
    ON e.eid = d.eid
 WHERE pid = ?
   AND edate BETWEEN ? AND ?";

if ($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $pid, $range_start_date, $range_end_date);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($eid, $description);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        // Output a row
        echo "<tr><td>$pid</td><td>$eid</td><td>$description</td></tr>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    die('Prepare failed: ' . $db->error); //TODO: better error handling
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: The variable type of edate is string : "2013-03-04"-"2014-05-07" How between x and y statement automatically decide the range of the string?

Comment: Do you mean `edate` column or `$edate`? If you're talking about `$edate` then you can explode it like this `list($range_start_date, $range_end_date) = explode('"-"', trim($edate, '"'));`. See updated answer for a complete example.